# Confusion as to how to derive integration factors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to sharpen my understanding re the following:

I am new to Differential Equations, and was recently taught how to find factors of integration by which to multiply existing formulas, in order to make them exact. I was taught that no set algorithm exists, but if I apply the formula $\frac {X_y-Y_x}{X}$ to the equation and I get a result that only depends on $y$; or conversely, apply the formula $\frac {X_y-Y_x}{Y}$ to the equation and get a result that only depends on $x$, I can use those results as integration factors.

I tried this with the equation $(x+y^2)dx-ydy=0$, and am left with $-2$ and $\frac{2y}{x+y^2}$ respectively, where the first one fits the criteria. Yet $e^{-2x}$ does not work to make this formula exact. By fluke I discovered that $\frac{1}{y^2}$ does do the trick, but cannot see how this integration factor is related to the instructions given above. Where is the mistake in my reasoning, and how should I have understood that $\frac{1}{y^2}$ is the correct integration factor?

Thank you!

Comment: But $y^{-2}$ is **not** an integrating factor.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Could you expand a bit? Maybe that's where my confusion stems from… I thought an integrating factor is the element one multiplies with in order to get an exact formula. Am I wrong?

Comment: I suspect you took the partial of the first term with respect to $x$ and got $\frac{1}{y^2}$ instead of taking the partial with respect to $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $e^{-2x} $ as the integrating factor and it works fine.

Note that $$\frac {d}{dy} e^{-2x }(x+y^2)=2e^{-2x}y=\frac {d}{dx}(-e^{-2x}y)$$
Thus the resulting equation is exact.

Comment: So the fact that $1/y^2$ is also an integration factor is by mere chance?

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{y^2}$ isn't an integrating factor. Recheck your work.

Answer (score 1):

It is easily checked that $\dfrac{1}{y^2}$ is not an integrating factor for

$$ (x+y^2)dx-ydy=0 $$

Given

$$ \left(\frac{x}{y^2}+1\right)\,dx-\frac{1}{y}\,dy$$

we get

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{x}{y^2}+1\right)=-\frac{2x}{y^3}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(-\frac{1}{y}\right)=0$$

So what was the mistake?

Note that if you take the partials with respect to the **wrong** variables, you will get $\dfrac{1}{y^2}$ in each case. I suspect that was the error made.